# Data loss during Redis master slave transition

Tags: java, redis, transactions, high-availability, sentinel

I am using UnifiedJedis to perform read and write operations on Redis. I'm facing an issue with data loss when there is a master and slave.

The issue with the Jedis transaction was when we shut down the master POD and another slave became the master, that time some of the objects were lost even though we got the OK response from the transaction.

In Unified Jedis I tried with `waitReplias()`, but I'm still facing the same issue.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: It sounds to me that this issue is happening because your replicas (note: Redis deprecated the use of the word "slave" and replaced it with "replica" some time ago) are quite a bit behind the master. So when the master fails and Sentinel fails over to a replica, it doesn't have recent data. However, since this is most likely solved with _configuration_ rather than _software_, I don't think this fits on SO. I'd recommend you ask this question on the StackExchange site ServerFault. Because it doesn't fit on SO, I'm marking that this question be closed in favor of a question on ServerFault.

Comment: @AdamMarshall thank you i will ask question on StackExchange